# How to manually dequantize the output of a layer and requantize it for the next layer in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, quantization

I am working on school project that requires me to perform manual quantization of each layer of a model. Specifically, I want to implement manually:

> Quantized activation, combined with quantized weight A - layer A -
> quantized output - dequantized output - requantized output, combined
> with quantized weight B - layer B - ...

I know Pytorch already have a quantization function, but that function is limited to int8. I would like to perform quantization from bit = 16 to bit = 2, and then compare their accuracy.

The issue I encountered is that after quantization, the output of a layer is multi-magnitude larger (with bit = 16), and I don't know how to dequantize it back. I am performing the quantization with the same min and max of both activation and weight. So here is an example:

```
Activation = [1,2,3,4]
Weight = [5,6,7,8]
Min and max across activation and weight = 1, 8
Expected, non-quantized output = 70

Quantize with bit = 16
Quantized activation = [-32768, -23406, -14044, -4681]
Quantized weight = [4681, 14043, 23405, 32767]
Quantized output = -964159613
Dequantize output with min = 1, max = 8 = -102980
```

The calculation makes sense to me, because the output involves multiplying activations and weigths, their magnitude increase is also multiplied together. If I perform dequantization once with the original min and max, it is reasonable to have a much larger output.

How does Pytorch handle dequantization? I attempted to locate the quantization of Pytorch, but I could not locate it. How to dequantize the output?

Comment: I guess you need to quantize with respect to min/max of possible *outputs*, not weights/activations. E.g. you can run the model on your dataset, find min/max for each layer's output - and use this to quantize, so afterwards quantized 0  means minimal possible output, and 2^16 - 1 means maximum possible output

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov That is what I considered at first. But there is an issue: If I use the original min and max to quantize the output, the output would fall far outside the min and max range. The quantized output would become either all 32767 or -32768. The problem lies with the dequantization process, I have to dequantize the output back to the original magnitude, then apply the original min and max for quantization.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an issue with your formula for calculating the dequantized output.

```
import numpy as np

# Original values
activation = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
weight = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

# Quantization parameters
bit = 16  # Desired bit precision
min_val = min(np.min(activation), np.min(weight))
max_val = max(np.max(activation), np.max(weight))

# Calculate scale factor
scale_factor = (2 ** (bit - 1) - 1) / max(abs(min_val), abs(max_val))

# Quantize activation and weight values
quantized_activation = np.round(activation * scale_factor).astype(np.int16)
quantized_weight = np.round(weight * scale_factor).astype(np.int16)

# Dequantize activation and weight values
dequantized_activation = quantized_activation / scale_factor
dequantized_weight = quantized_weight / scale_factor

# Print values
print("Original activation:", activation)
print("Original weight:", weight)
print("Minimum value:", min_val)
print("Maximum value:", max_val)
print("Scale factor:", scale_factor)
print("Quantized activation:", quantized_activation)
print("Quantized weight:", quantized_weight)
print("Dequantized activation:", dequantized_activation)
print("Dequantized weight:", dequantized_weight)

---------------------------------------------------------

Original activation: [1 2 3 4]
Original weight: [5 6 7 8]
Minimum value: 1
Maximum value: 8
Scale factor: 4095.875
Quantized activation: [ 4096  8192 12288 16384]
Quantized weight: [20479 24575 28671 32767]
Dequantized activation: [1.00003052 2.00006104 3.00009156 4.00012207]
Dequantized weight: [4.99990844 5.99993896 6.99996948 8.        ]
```

Calculate output:

```
output = np.sum(dequantized_activation * dequantized_weight)
print("Dequantized output:", output) # 70.00183110125477
```

Comment: I think, from my understanding, the dequantized output in this case is based on the dequantized activation and weigths.
But what I want is to pass the quantized activation and weights directly to the layer, obtain an output, then dequantize this output, re-quantize it, pass it to the next layer.

Comment: @longbow I somehow feel it's impossible to dequantize the output, because it depends on how the layer computes output from activation and weights, e.g. maybe in the layer there is some weird formula like a*(w1^w2) and then who the hell knows the exact range of outputs.